# On session timeout capture info

Tags: asp.net

Trying to implement data to be saved on the session timeout.how can i capture the `session timeout event`.

Comment: what you really want, no one can understand with single line of question..please provide more details and what you have tried..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to implement `Session_End` event in `Global.asax`, The Session_End event is raised at the end of a request when the Abandon method has been called or when the session has expired. A session expires when the number of minutes specified by the Timeout property passes without a request being made for the session. [**MSDN reference**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatemodule.end.aspx)

```
publicvoid Session_OnEnd()
{
    //Saving of data goes here.    
}
```